# adding sqljdbc jar in android studio throws app:transformClassesWithDexFroDebug Exception

Tags: sql-server, android-studio, build.gradle

adding sqljdbc jar in android studio throws app:transformClassesWithDexFroDebug Exception.
I am trying to connect to sqlserver hence added sqljdbc42.jar in libs folder when I remove the jar all work fine but I need to add jar to achieve DB connectivity. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

I have also added path of sqljdbc42.jar path in Classpath.

This is my build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.cropin.automationtesting"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/bsh-2.0b4.jar')
    compile files('libs/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/guava-19.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/jcommander-1.48.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/netty-3.5.7.Final.jar')
    compile files('libs/phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/selenium-java-2.53.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/selenium-java-2.53.0-srcs.jar')
    compile files('libs/testng-6.9.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqljdbc42.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error realized that to make it sucessful use latest SeleniumJars .
I changed my testing framework from TestNG to Junit.

set classpath in Sytem Variables with sql jar file path.

With the above changes I was able to start automating my test cases with SQL Server